# How to update values in an Association using a pattern?

Tags: associations, insert

Say, having an association:

```
asc = <|"a" -> 5, "b" -> 4, "c" -> 21|>
```

I can updated values like:

```
In[1]:= AssociateTo[asc, {"a" -> 1, "b" -> 2, "c" -> 3}]

Out[1]= <|"a" -> 1, "b" -> 2, "c" -> 3|>
```

When trying to do that within a list, like:

```
AssociateTo[asc, {# -> 1}] & /@ {"a", "b", "c"}
```

I get the association multiplied by the keys count I try to update (1 update per iteration):

```
{<|"a" -> 1|>, <|"a" -> 1, "b" -> 1|>, <|a" -> 1, "b" -> 1, "c" -> 1|>}
```

What is wrong here?

Thanks!

Comment: `AssociateTo` will both *permanently change* its argument (which is unusual among Mathematica functions) and *return* the new value.  Your `Map` line will both *permanently change* `asc`, but it will also return the result of each functions application in a list, as `Map` normally would.

Comment: What's the solution to avoid that behavior?

Comment: There is something wrong in the last output of your post (what is `"e"` ... ?). You probably copied/pasted the wrong example.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have applied Mapping wrongly. What you need is:

```
In[8]:= AssociateTo[asc, # -> 1 & /@ {"a", "b", "c"}]

Out[8]= <|"a" -> 1, "b" -> 1, "c" -> 1|>
```

Answer (score 4):

You can also use [`Part` `[[...]]`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Part.html) on Association as you would on any expression:

```
asc = <|"a" -> 5, "b" -> 4, "c" -> 21|>;

asc[[{"a", "b", "xyz"}]] = 1;

asc
```

> `<|a->1,b->1,c->21,xyz->1|>`